# How to make an API call inside for loop, withour using async await

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a for loop inside a promise. How can i get response from getData API without using async await. The parameters used inside getData are coming from for loop.

```
var res = EService.webApi.get.GetActiveData(formModel.project.EID);
        res.then(
           async function (result) {
                //success
                var data = result.data;
                var eList= data.BodyData;
                var jList= [];
                for (var i = 0; i < eList.length; i++) {
                        let entity = await getData(eList[i].EntityID);
                        if (eList[i].typeID !== 16) {
                            jList.push({
                                Name: eList[i].Name + " - " + e[i].typeName + " - " + entity.Name,
                                EID: eList[i].EntityID,
                                model: eList[i],
                            });
                        } 
                    }
}
```

Comment: _"Having a for loop inside a promise..."_ - There's only one `Promise` "visible" in your example and that's the return value of `getData()`

Comment: _"How can i get response from getData API without using async await"_ - Why?

Comment: You can use [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) instead.

Comment: _"The parameters used inside getData are coming from for loop"_ - Did you test this before asking? There's only one `i` which will cause `eList[i].typeID` to throw an error.

Comment: @Andreas : i added up the actual promise code. using Await inside loops can affect performance. so i wanted to check if i can do it other way.

Comment: _"...can affect performance"_ - The "overhead" of a loop compared to a bunch of network requests is totally neglectable. And even if not... Only a profiler can tell you the actual problem/bottleneck of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, it sounds like you want to invoke all of the async requests right away but have each one await its result, rather than invoking them in serial where each one awaits the previous operation.  Maybe something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < eList.length; i++) {
  (async (j) => {
    // The rest of your logic, but using the passed `j` instead of `i`
  })(i);
}
```

The anonymous `async` function isn't awaited, but internally each call to that function can `await` the call to `getData` to use its result.

Though if you want to do something with `jList` or any other result/side-effect afterward then you'd need to await the whole thing.  Maybe put all of the promises into an array and await the array.  Perhaps something like:

```
let promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < eList.length; i++) {
  promises.push((async (j) => {
    // The rest of your logic, but using the passed `j` instead of `i`
  })(i));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => ...);
```

The overall goal being that all of the operations run in parallel, rather than in serial like in the original loop.